# Ошбика при установки модуля Python ip2geotools

Tags: python

я использую VisualStudio Code, чистую (сегодня переустанавливал)

Вот что выдаёт консоль:

```
    ERROR: Error [WinError 2] Не удается найти указанный файл while executing command python setup.py egg_info
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [WinError 2] Не удается найти указанный файл
```

Скриншот консоли

[image: Скриншот консоли]

версия PIP - 21.1.2

Comment: Вот вы часть пути замазали, а нет ли там русских букв, пробелов и т.п.? Не все пакеты с ними нормально умеют работать.

Comment: Попробуйте запустить консоль от имени администратора. Если ошибка повторится проверьте путь к файлам python.exe и pip они должны быть указаны в Windows PATH

Comment: @CrazyElf я замазал имя, в целях анонимизации, оно написано на русском

Comment: @NastyStuffy Так то вы это сделали правильно, но проблема может быть именно в русских буквах, не все пакеты нормально ставятся по таким путям

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я нашёл решение проблемы, она заключалась в том что некоторые модули не поддерживают x64 архитектуру ( [image: Скриншот] )

И исправил я эту проблему так, скачал установщик python x32 и x64 (x64 для деинсталляции)
и установил 32 битный питон, который уже скачал нужные мне модули.